# windows phone 7 wifi , bluetooth

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bluetooth, wifi, windows-phone-8

I have few queries aboubt network statistics for application development on windows phone.

1)Is there any way(APIS), we can scan wifi AP in windows?
If it is connected to AP how to get SSID,BSSID and MAC address?

2)how to get CELL ID and local information?

3)Application Layer (TCP, UDP & ICP throughput, latency, etc)?

4) Bluetooth apis for device connected and device?

I was finding very info from msdn.
like Bluetooth connect and discover able devices.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx

coming to (wifi,cellular,ethernet) they have mention common class networkinformatio will it be  helpful?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202867(v=vs.105).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: There are too many questions here for a single answer. Posts here should contain a single, specific, answerable question. If you have multiple questions, you need to break them down into individual questions that can be specifically answered. Please edit to do so; as it is now, this can't be answered directly and therefore isn't suitable for this site's format. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more details about how to ask questions here in a way that will allow them to be answered. Thanks.

Comment: There are other answers for 1), 2) on StackOverflow so please search for those. (in short, not possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answers to big questions:

1. You cannot find WiFi SSIDs and Mac address directly from the WP8 SDK.
2. You cannot get information on the physical layout of the cellular netwrok directly from the WP8 SDK.
3. You cannot get network transport statistics directly from the WP8 SDK.
4. You can use Bluetooth APIs to enumerate over paired devices and open BT-SPP sockets.

Comment: And for WP7, number 4 is not possible either.